# Is this iterative inorder traversal algorithm well-known?

Tags: python, c++, algorithm, binary-tree

I was concerned about the approach in Morris traversal algorithm and came up with simpler solution that uses parent pointers in nodes.

The constraints were following:

- Time Complexity: O(n)
- Space Complexity: O(1)
- Implementation: iterative

Node structure:

```py
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data, left=None, right=None):
        self.data = data
        self.left = left
        if self.left is not None:
            self.left.parent = self
        self.right = right
        if self.right is not None:
            self.right.parent = self
        self.parent = None
```

### Algorithm

```
1. Get the the leftmost node of the root of the tree.
2. Yield the node.
3. Check if the node has a right child.
4. If it has a right child, find the leftmost node of the right child.
5. If it doesn't have a right child
 i. Go up the tree until you find a node that is not right child of its parent.
 ii. Go to the parent of that node.
8. Repeat from step 2 until the node is None.
```

```py
def iterative_inorder(root):
    cur = root
    # Navigate to the leftmost node
    while cur and cur.left:
        cur = cur.left

    while cur:
        yield cur.data

        # If right child exists, visit this subtree
        if cur.right:
            cur = cur.right
            while cur.left:
                cur = cur.left
        else:
            # Traverse back up to the parent
            while cur.parent and cur == cur.parent.right:
                cur = cur.parent
            cur = cur.parent
```

```cpp
void iterativeInorder(Node* root) {
    Node* cur = root;

    // Find the leftmost node
    while (cur && cur->left) {
        cur = cur->left;
    }

    while (cur) {
        std::cout << cur->data << " "; // Output the data

        // Traverse the right subtree
        if (cur->right) {
            cur = cur->right;
            while (cur->left) {
                cur = cur->left;
            }
        } else {
            // Move up the tree
            while (cur->parent && cur == cur->parent->right) {
                cur = cur->parent;
            }
            cur = cur->parent;
        }
    }
}
```

I was curious if anyone has seen implementation like that (since it is overly simple) and if I should post it somewhere for all people who are interested in different algorithms, because it was interesting at least for me and my coworkers.

I have done some research on the internet and basically every link goes to Morris traversal, so I am genuinely curious if I can make my small contribution to the algorithm solutions. I would be grateful if anyone could link a reference or something like that if they have seen something very similar.

Comment: The space complexity isn't \$O(1)\$ since you require adding \$n\$ `parent`s.

Comment: Read this https://stlab.cc/2020/12/01/forest-introduction.html. I think you are doing something similar. There is a sean parent talk where he goes into more details

Comment: @Peilonrayz can you explain how the complexity of the algorithm by itself is not O(1), because I seem to loose the point. thank you

Comment: @AjinkyaKamat thank you for your input, i will definitely take a look

Comment: @Max Morris traversal works on a binary tree -- has `left` and `right`. For your algorithm to work you need to add `parent` to every `Node` (\$n\$ nodes). In comparison to the Morris traversal your algorithm uses \$O(n)\$ additional memory by adding `parent` to every node.

Comment: @Peilonrayz I see. Makes sense. I would actually argue that it is constant for this specific implementation of node, but it makes sense. Thank you for your input

Comment: **Threaded binary trees** are a bit faster to iterate over; they can also be optimized to have a bit less memory overhead too.